# Most effecient way to solve a formula in javascript

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following formula

```
a + (13 * (b/c)) + d + (12 * e) - f - 11 + (g * (h/i)) - 10 = 66;
```

Now the letters a-i can represent a number from 1-9.  However, each number can only be used once.  What would be the most efficient way to solve this?  The way I have at the moment is to generate an array of random numbers e.g.

```
array[2,5,1,7,8,6,9,3,4]
```

I then fit this into the formula to check if it equals 66.  If not, I generate a new array of numbers.  I was thinking there should be a better way to do this though, maybe using recursion?

Just wanted to get some input in how you would tackle this?

Thanks

Comment: The naive solution: to bruteforce. Just create N inner loops over every letter and check if it matches. For the expression evaluation you will have to build some expression parser though.

Comment: You will want to look up the term "permutations". No need to use random numbers (and a quite bad idea as well).

Comment: Do you need all solutions, or just the first you can find?

Comment: Btw, relevant: http://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/05/11/using-monads-in-c-to-solve-constraints-1-the-list-monad/

Comment: e cannot be 9 nor 8. Also, formula can be simplified to `a + (13 * (b/c)) + d + (12 * e) - f + (g * (h/i)) = 87;` That should help when calculating permutations...

Comment: The solution I currently have is bruteforcing.  I am a bit confused how permutations could be used for this so wondering what the process would be.  Looking to get all possible results.

Comment: @NickPrice if you randomly generate arrays you don't exclude to have the same array generated twice. Permutations would ensure this.

Comment: @NickPrice: …and there is no guarantee that your random array generation will ever yield a permutation that is the solution.

Comment: If it's always 66 then some manual pre-analysis of the ranges for each constant would reduce the number of possible permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no smarter algorithm than just trying with each permutation of the numbers in the set for equality. Which I think will be easier for you, than creating everytime an unique array, that was not already generated.

In the code bellow I have used very primitive check for equality between numbers. There might be an easier way from the standard javascript library (e.g. if number is found in the predefined set...)

```
var solutions = [];

for (var a = 1; a <= 9; a++) {
  for (var b = 1; b <= 9; b++) {
    if ( b == a ) continue;
    for (var c = 1; c <= 9; c++) {
      if ( c == b || c == a ) continue;
      for (var d = 1; d <= 9; d++) {
        if ( d == c || d == b || d == a ) continue;
        for (var e = 1; e <= 9; e++) {
          if ( e == d || e == c || e == b || e == a ) continue;
          for (var f = 1; f <= 9; f++) {
            if ( f == e || f == d || f == c || f == b || f == a ) continue;
            for (var g = 1; g <= 9; g++) {
              if ( g == f || g == e || g == d || g == c || g == b || g == a ) continue;
              for (var h = 1; h <= 9; h++) {
                if ( h == g || h == f || h == e || h == d || h == c || h == b || h == a ) continue;
                for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                  if ( i == h || i == g || i == f || i == e || i == d || i == c || i == b || i == a ) continue;

                  if ((a + (13 * (b/c)) + d + (12 * e) - f - 11 + (g * (h/i)) - 10) == 66) {
                    solutions.push(a + "," + b + "," + c + "," + d + "," + e + "," + f + "," + g + "," + h + "," + i);
                  }

                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(solutions);
```

Which results into a lot of solutions

```
["1,2,6,4,7,8,3,5,9", "1,2,6,4,7,8,5,3,9", "1,3,2,4,5,8,7,9,6", "1,3,2,4,5,8,9,7,6", "1,3,2,9,5,6,4,7,8", "1,3,2,9,5,6,7,4,8", "1,3,4,7,6,5,2,9,8", "1,3,4,7,6,5,9,2,8", "1,3,6,2,7,9,4,5,8", "1,3,6,2,7,9,5,4,8", "1,3,9,4,7,8,2,5,6", "1,3,9,4,7,8,5,2,6", "1,4,8,2,7,9,3,5,6", "1,4,8,2,7,9,5,3,6", "1,5,2,3,4,8,7,9,6", "1,5,2,3,4,8,9,7,6", "1,5,2,8,4,7,3,9,6", "1,5,2,8,4,7,9,3,6", "1,5,3,9,4,2,7,8,6", "1,5,3,9,4,2,8,7,6", "1,9,6,4,5,8,3,7,2", "1,9,6,4,5,8,7,3,2", "1,9,6,7,5,2,3,4,8", "1,9,6,7,5,2,4,3,8", "2,1,4,3,7,9,5,6,8", "2,1,4,3,7,9,6,5,8", "2,3,6,1,7,9,4,5,8", "2,3,6,1,7,9,5,4,8", "2,4,8,1,7,9,3,5,6", "2,4,8,1,7,9,5,3,6", "2,8,6,9,4,1,5,7,3", "2,8,6,9,4,1,7,5,3", "2,9,6,3,5,1,4,7,8", "2,9,6,3,5,1,7,4,8", "3,1,4,2,7,9,5,6,8", "3,1,4,2,7,9,6,5,8", "3,2,1,5,4,7,8,9,6", "3,2,1,5,4,7,9,8,6", "3,2,4,8,5,1,7,9,6", "3,2,4,8,5,1,9,7,6", "3,2,8,6,5,1,7,9,4", "3,2,8,6,5,1,9,7,4", "3,5,2,1,4,8,7,9,6", "3,5,2,1,4,8,9,7,6", "3,6,4,9,5,8,1,7,2", "3,6,4,9,5,8,7,1,2", "3,9,2,8,1,5,6,7,4", "3,9,2,8,1,5,7,6,4", "3,9,6,2,5,1,4,7,8", "3,9,6,2,5,1,7,4,8", "4,2,6,1,7,8,3,5,9", "4,2,6,1,7,8,5,3,9", "4,3,2,1,5,8,7,9,6", "4,3,2,1,5,8,9,7,6", "4,3,9,1,7,8,2,5,6", "4,3,9,1,7,8,5,2,6", "4,9,6,1,5,8,3,7,2", "4,9,6,1,5,8,7,3,2", "5,1,2,9,6,7,3,4,8", "5,1,2,9,6,7,4,3,8", "5,2,1,3,4,7,8,9,6", "5,2,1,3,4,7,9,8,6", "5,3,1,7,2,6,8,9,4", "5,3,1,7,2,6,9,8,4", "5,4,1,9,2,7,3,8,6", "5,4,1,9,2,7,8,3,6", "5,4,8,9,6,7,1,3,2", "5,4,8,9,6,7,3,1,2", "5,7,2,8,3,9,1,6,4", "5,7,2,8,3,9,6,1,4", "5,9,3,6,2,1,7,8,4", "5,9,3,6,2,1,8,7,4", "6,2,8,3,5,1,7,9,4", "6,2,8,3,5,1,9,7,4", "6,3,1,9,2,5,7,8,4", "6,3,1,9,2,5,8,7,4", "6,9,3,5,2,1,7,8,4", "6,9,3,5,2,1,8,7,4", "7,1,4,9,6,5,2,3,8", "7,1,4,9,6,5,3,2,8", "7,2,8,9,6,5,1,3,4", "7,2,8,9,6,5,3,1,4", "7,3,1,5,2,6,8,9,4", "7,3,1,5,2,6,9,8,4", "7,3,2,8,5,9,1,6,4", "7,3,2,8,5,9,6,1,4", "7,3,4,1,6,5,2,9,8", "7,3,4,1,6,5,9,2,8", "7,5,2,8,4,9,1,3,6", "7,5,2,8,4,9,3,1,6", "7,6,4,8,5,9,1,3,2", "7,6,4,8,5,9,3,1,2", "7,9,6,1,5,2,3,4,8", "7,9,6,1,5,2,4,3,8", "8,2,4,3,5,1,7,9,6", "8,2,4,3,5,1,9,7,6", "8,3,2,7,5,9,1,6,4", "8,3,2,7,5,9,6,1,4", "8,5,2,1,4,7,3,9,6", "8,5,2,1,4,7,9,3,6", "8,5,2,7,4,9,1,3,6", "8,5,2,7,4,9,3,1,6", "8,6,4,7,5,9,1,3,2", "8,6,4,7,5,9,3,1,2", "8,7,2,5,3,9,1,6,4", "8,7,2,5,3,9,6,1,4", "8,9,2,3,1,5,6,7,4", "8,9,2,3,1,5,7,6,4", "9,1,2,5,6,7,3,4,8", "9,1,2,5,6,7,4,3,8", "9,1,4,7,6,5,2,3,8", "9,1,4,7,6,5,3,2,8", "9,2,8,7,6,5,1,3,4", "9,2,8,7,6,5,3,1,4", "9,3,1,6,2,5,7,8,4", "9,3,1,6,2,5,8,7,4", "9,3,2,1,5,6,4,7,8", "9,3,2,1,5,6,7,4,8", "9,4,1,5,2,7,3,8,6", "9,4,1,5,2,7,8,3,6", "9,4,8,5,6,7,1,3,2", "9,4,8,5,6,7,3,1,2", "9,5,3,1,4,2,7,8,6", "9,5,3,1,4,2,8,7,6", "9,6,4,3,5,8,1,7,2", "9,6,4,3,5,8,7,1,2", "9,8,6,2,4,1,5,7,3", "9,8,6,2,4,1,7,5,3"]
```

If the formula is only this, and will not change, you might try to think if there are ranges that are not included in the result set per definition. For example, if you find that some of the numbers cannot be 9, you should not iterate to 9. E.g. the multiplications in the formula might exceed a number that even added to the minimal values in the other variables to exceed 66.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force method:

```js
function findSolution() {
  for (var a = 1; a <= 9; a++) {
    for (var b = 1; b <= 9; b++) {
      for (var c = 1; c <= 9; c++) {
        for (var d = 1; d <= 9; d++) {
          for (var e = 1; e <= 9; e++) {
            for (var f = 1; f <= 9; f++) {
              for (var g = 1; g <= 9; g++) {
                for (var h = 1; h <= 9; h++) {
                  for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                    if (
                      [b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i].indexOf(a) >= 0 ||
                      [a,c,d,e,f,g,h,i].indexOf(b) >= 0 ||
                      [a,b,d,e,f,g,h,i].indexOf(c) >= 0 ||
                      [a,b,c,e,f,g,h,i].indexOf(d) >= 0 ||
                      [a,b,c,d,f,g,h,i].indexOf(e) >= 0 ||
                      [a,b,c,d,e,g,h,i].indexOf(f) >= 0 ||
                      [a,b,c,d,e,f,h,i].indexOf(g) >= 0 ||
                      [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,i].indexOf(h) >= 0 ||
                      [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h].indexOf(i) >= 0
                    ) {
                      continue;
                    }

                    if (a + (13 * (b/c)) + d + (12 * e) - f - 11 + (g * (h/i)) - 10 === 66) {
                      return [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i];
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('result').innerText = findSolution().join(', ')
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```